# ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException?

Tags: imageresizer

Recently I noticed that one of the production site is throwing loads of the ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException errors. At the same time RAM consumption increases dramatically leading to app pool recycle.

```
ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException (0x80004005): Failed to acquire a lock on file "E:\wwwroot\imagecache\1e\d1a022809295f272d4dc7c63377a759c0f336be0a1be8ca696fcf27479892cf1.jpg" within 15000ms. Caching failed.
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString, IVirtualFile vf)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This is not a permanent issues. it does occur once or twice a day and lasts for 30-60 minutes. IIS restarts are not helping.... the rezizer is creating  empty files (0 bytes). What is also interesting that the problem mostly occurs on 2 out of 3 web servers (it will start on one of them and the second will go tits up a few minutes later). The servers sort themselves out afer 45-90 minutes.

ImageResizer version: 3.4.2

What I tried:
 - Upgrading to latest version
 - Clearing image cache folder
 - Enabling asyncwrties

Any idea what could be going on here?

Thanks,
M

Comment: Does the diagnostics page say anything? 3.4.2 is not the latest version.

Comment: Hi, Diagnostics page does not flag any issues. We can't upgrade to 4 as this version is shipped with the product we do use. It was all fine until last Thursday .... can't really figure it out!

Comment: Can you post the diagnostics page? We need something to work with.

Comment: Hi All,

In the meantime I upgraded the lib to the latest version (4.0.5). The issue did go away... but guess what - it's back.

Diagnostics: http://pastebin.com/kjLsm7Qn
Thanks!

Comment: How many files are in imagecache/*? I think you probably haven't set `subfolders` to an appropriate value, and disk churn is simply that high.

Comment: We're experiencing this whenever we slot swap in Azure (the DiskCache cache is in the App Service local storage). @LilithRiver, what is considered an 'appropriate' value for `subfolders`? Currently we use `<diskcache dir="~/images/cache" subfolders="1024" autoClean="true" asyncWrites="true" />` to limit the size of the cache.